# Remove "NSObject may not respond to selector" warning when using a formal protocol?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to write a custom, formal protocol and I am having issues with Xcode's warnings. Specifically:

```
if([self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(myProtocol)]){
    [self.delegate myProtocolMethod];
}
```

This works totally fine at runtime, but Xcode keeps giving me the "NSObject may not respond to -myProtocolMethod" warning. I'd really like to remove the warning, so am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler doesn't care if you just checked for the protocol. It only cares about the data type of the object you are calling the method on. The easiest thing to do is simply cast the result of `self.delegate` to a type which declares the protocol.

```
if([self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(myProtocol)]) {
    [(NSObject * <myProtocol>)self.delegate myProtocolMethod];
}
```

Or, if the delegate property is supposed to *always* implement this protocol, you can change the property declaration to include it. This is even better because the compiler will warn you if you try to assign an object which doesn't implement the protocol as the delegate.

```
@property (modifiers) NSObject * <myProtocol> delegate;
```

Comment: I generally recommend using `id` here rather than `NSObject`. Then make sure that `<myProtocol>` inherits from `<NSObject>`. This allows `NSProxy` objects to work correctly. And always name protocols with a leading cap of course.

Comment: @RobNapier I was going to use `id`, but since the OP's error mentions `NSObject`, I thought I should use it instead. Good point though.

Comment: This should be a piece of cake for the compiler to check, shouldn't it? I mean, if it is an **Objective C** compiler, which it is... Now it's acting like a C/C++ compiler.

Casts are dangerous.

Answer (score 3):

You're seeing the warning because the type of `self.delegate`, whatever it happens to be, does not declare that method.

Cast `self.delegate` to the correct class or protocol to remove the warning.  E.g.:

```
[(id<myProtocol>)self.delegate myProtocolMethod];
```